# Run task in Azure pipeline only if the Pull request is being merged

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am updating an Azure pipeline which has a set of tests that are run. I am producing an xml output for them (they are based on `gtest`).
I want to publish the result of these tests with `PublishTestResults` task. However I only want to run them when merging the pull request into the master branch.

How does one go about doing it?

Here is the piece of code for it,

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
     testResultsFormat: cTest
     testResultsFiles: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/build/Testing/*/Test.xml
     testRunTitle: UnitTest PR $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
  displayName: Publish unittest results
  condition: always()
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
     testResultsFormat: jUnit
     testResultsFiles: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/FunctionalTests.xml
     testRunTitle: FunctionalTest PR $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
  displayName: Publish functional test results
  condition: always()
```

As `condition` I put always so that these two tasks run even if others fail but as I said I want the two tasks to only run when the PR is being merged into master.

Comment: Could you clarify: do you want these to be run in the pipeline triggered by the PR on the temporary merge branch (i.e. while the PR is active), or in the pipeline triggered by the merge into master (i.e. after the PR has completed)?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I want them to run when triggered by the merge into master. The second scenario that you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple to check for the [source branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables) in a condition, using the right pre-defined variable and the right comparison function:

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
```

But that's not enough by itself; you don't want to run if the pipeline is triggered manually or on a schedule, so you need a check on the build reason:

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')
```

but there are actually two values for build reason which might be valid, so you want to allow for either of them like this:

```
condition: in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI')
```

The last part of the condition is that you do want these tasks to run even if the pipeline has already failed, but not if it has been cancelled, so the [succeededOrFailed function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#succeededorfailed) is necessary. Putting them all together using the `and()` function, this is the condition you need:

```
condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI'))
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. Thanks