# Azure DevOps Pipelines Condition

Tags: if-statement, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Trying to find the right condition to run job only after PR doing merge to master only.

I tried it but still after merge the job did not run:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), variables['System.PullRequest'], 'PullRequest')
```

Comment: Hi Nitro5, and welcome to Stack Overflow. A very similar question has been asked before, and I think the answer will help you: [Run task in Azure pipeline only if the Pull request is being merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992161/run-task-in-azure-pipeline-only-if-the-pull-request-is-being-merged)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really one. After the merge completes, it's just seen as any other push to master.

You can probably use the REST API against Azure Repos to find whether that commit is associated to a pull request, but you only get the pull request context for the validation builds, not for the build that triggers on the completed merge result.

Comment: And is there a condition that a "PR Automated" or "Individual CI" run type will not run a particular Job?

Comment: No. There is no way to use a condition to see whether the CI build was triggered by a direct commit or the closing of a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable named i.e. `isPullRequest`:

```yaml
variables:
  isPullRequest: ${{eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')}}
```

Then in the condition of the job that you want to skip in Pull Requests:

```yaml
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isPullRequest, 'false'))
```

Comment: I added the condition, and it still runs the Job after doing Merge in PR and the Pipeline runs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use below condition:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceVersionMessage'], 'Merge pull request'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below condition to to run steps only when merging into the master branch

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```