# How to use conditions in Build and deploy?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YML file which will build and then deploy in one YML file. However i need to add a condition to only deploy if the branch changed is master. How can i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run task in Azure pipeline only if the Pull request is being merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992161/run-task-in-azure-pipeline-only-if-the-pull-request-is-being-merged)

Comment: would you put this line above the deploy code ?   Does Yaml execute in sequence ?                                        
condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')